# Postgres triggers: write old record to new table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-delete, database-trigger

I have a set of different tables that have a trigger on DELETE. I'd like to write deleted rows to a like table on a different schema.

For example, say I have a couple different tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A (val1 TEXT, val2 TEXT)
CREATE TABLE B (someval1 INT, someval2 TEXT, someval3 TEXT)
```

And I have copies of these same tables on some other schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA backup;
CREATE TABLE backup.A (like A);
CREATE TABLE backup.B (like B);
```

Each non-backup table A & B has a trigger for deletions (written in plpgsql). If I delete a record from either of these tables, how can I write a trigger function that writes the deleted record to the associated backup table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to write the deleted record to my backup tables using a single, non-table specific trigger function:

```
create or replace function track_delete() returns trigger as
$body$
BEGIN
    execute format('insert into backup.%I values($1.*)', tg_table_name) USING old;
END;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a trigger indeed. You need one trigger per table, like:

```
create or replace function func_backup_tablea_before_delete()
return trigger as
$body$
begin
    insert into backup.tablea(val1, val2) values (old.val1, old.val2);
end;
$body$ 

create trigger trg_delete_a 
before delete on tablea
for each row
execute procedure func_backup_tablea_before_delete;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it with a single function for all tables as there are more than a few tables in my real situation :(